# A question about prime-gaps whose sum is a power of $2$.

Tags: number-theory

I found this prime: $127163$ such that $127163+26$ is the next prime and $127163-6$ is the previous prime, I mean $127163-6$, $127163$ and $127163+26$ are three consecutive primes. As you can see, the sum of the gaps (the gap between the original prime and the previous prime plus the gap between the original prime and the next prime) is $32=26+6$, a power of $2$. Are there other examples of such primes for which the sum of the gaps is a power of $2$?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot.  Here are some early examples for each power of $2$ showing the three consecutive primes:

- $2^2: \qquad 3,5,7$ (only example this size)
- $2^3: \qquad 23,29,31$ (large number of examples this size)
- $2^4: \qquad 211,223,227$
- $2^5: \qquad 4751,4759,4783$
- $2^6: \qquad 33223, 33247, 33287$

Comment: for $2^5$ have you some example apart $127163$?

Comment: @homunculus $4759,5557,6397,6947,7621,7759,8389,9067,10223,\ldots$ as the central prime

Answer (score 0):

$31-2, 31, 31+6=29,31,37$ and $2+6=8=2^3$.

$53,59,61$,

$59,61,67$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: $3,5,7$. Consecutive primes with sum of gaps $2+2 = 4 = 2^2$. [Here](https://oeis.org/A001223) is the sequence of prime gaps. I think you can find many more examples with it.

Comment: Examples with the sum of gaps>$2^5$?

Comment: @homunculus Unfortunately I don't have any, being not that great at computational number theory, but I did find a few more examples of prime-gap sum $32$ in a list of the first $1000$ prime gaps. One of them is $7757,7759,7789$.